# Cannot SSH to Server after OpenSSH upgrade

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ssh, openssh

One of my developers has taken it upon himself to update one of our production servers without backup to OpenSSH 6.2p, this server is and ubuntu box running in EC2, and now we are unable to SSH to it here is an output log from the SSH command.

```
ssh -i ~/Security/microsites_lamp.pem ubuntu@our.ip.address.here -v
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/justin/.ssh/config
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to our.ip.address.here [our.ip.address.here] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/justin/Security/microsites_lamp.pem type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/justin/Security/microsites_lamp.pem-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA <RSA_FINGERPRINT_HERE>
debug1: Host 'our.ip.address.here' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/justin/.ssh/known_hosts:20
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/justin/Security/microsites_lamp.pem
debug1: read PEM private key done: type RSA
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

I have ensured that the PEM file has the correct permissions and the server is running but now I am stuck, is there anything that can be done?

Comment: No console access of any sort? You could run sshd in debug mode (`/usr/sbin/sshd -rddd`) to see why it refuses the login.

Comment: In OS X what command would I need to get debug stuff?

Comment: Uh, you said the server runs Ubuntu, not OS X?